# How to activate the countdown after the page loads up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There is some odometer items in template that I want to use for the my Website ( My programming language is : Asp.net Core ) :

[image: 1]

**The countdown effect occurs when it is visible to the user ( like when page scroll to that )**

my Problem is that : this section is in the main banner of the site (below the header) and the countdown effect ends before the page loads. **Because the page is in the countdown desired position before load**

**And When the page is loaded, only the final result of the countdown is displayed! (simple text without effect) :**

[image: 2]

This is my code :

```
    <div class="funfacts-area">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in LandingItems)
        {
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-6 col-sm-3">
            <div class="funfact">
                <h3><span class="odometer" data-count="@item.count" dir="ltr">00</span>+</h3>
                <p>@item.name</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**This code only works when : Use Ctrl + F5 ( clear cache ) in the middle of the page and scroll to the top banner** : The countdown effect is then activated and start counting...

I tried to send this code as a **PartialViewResult** to View after full load { **jquery: windows.onload ()** }. But Unfortunately, **countdown cannot detect the user position** for countdown activation **and the values are 00**

[image: 3]

**What is the solution to this problem? Please Help me...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Re-value the Html content to reactivate the odometer countdown :**

```
        $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('.odometer').each(function () {
            $(this).html("-");
            $(this).html($(this).data("count"));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using EventListener.
Executes after DOM is loaded (before img and css):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //....
});
```

Or

Exectues after everything is loaded and parsed:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    // ....
})
```

Comment: I should Use this to load PartialViewResult ? ( Unfortunately didn't work! ) :

Comment: You should use it to inject <div class="funfacts-area"> with children into another div. The inside of EventListener should look like this: document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = <div class="funfacts-area">...

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work!
**But I solved the problem with a new answer that you can see.**